# Error: mysql: Failed to download resource "tcl-tk--tcllib"

Tags: python, mysql, homebrew

I'm trying to install mysql and mysql-client lib, when I write the command `brew install mysql`, before the downloading start this warning appears

> Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
> We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
> You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
> Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrews GitHub,
> Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
> any issues you experience while you are running this
> old version.

Then this error appears

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to netactuate.dl.sourceforge.net port 443: Operation timed out`

`Error: mysql: Failed to download resource "tcl-tk--tcllib"`

`Download failed: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/tcllib/tcllib/1.20/tcllib-1.20.tar.xz`

I already update the brew `brew update Already up-to-date.`